# How can I tell firebase if I'm in development or production? (For firebase functions sandbox/live switch)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, next.js

I have some firebase functions that I test locally, but I really don't want to have to rely on remembering to switch a flag, or explicitly set the values. Is there a value I can check in firebase to tell if it's in dev or prod? I'm also using NextJS, so I don't mind changing it on the next side either. Just whatever way makes the most sense within the firebase ecosystem. Thanks!

The invocation of client inside my function (on firebase):

```
const env = new checkoutNodeSDK.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret)
```

My firebase.js file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/functions'
const dev = true


export const app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "REDACTED",
  authDomain: "edit-elements.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://edit-elements-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "edit-elements",
  storageBucket: "edit-elements.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "340652433701",
  appId: "1:340652433701:web:a26472592c1538bbac7acc",
  measurementId: "G-945XC7348K"
}) : firebase.app()

const auth = app.auth()
const db = app.firestore()
const functions = app.functions()
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  functions.useEmulator('localhost', 5001)
  db.useEmulator('localhost', 8080)
}
export { auth, db, functions }
```

I want to set something like:

```
const env = flagDev ? new checkoutNodeSDK.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret) : new checkoutNodeSDK.core.LiveEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret)
```

TL;DR - When the function is called in dev, I want the function to use the Sandbox credentials. In prod, I want to use the live sandbox credentials.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have a sense of "dev" or "prod".  It's up to you to define what that means and how to configure it in your code.  Usually people set up different projects for each environment, and the ID of the project tells you what the current configuration is.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: Could I specify a flag var during the build command? I'm specifically referencing the firebase functions. It's just weird to have to manually swap out the sandbox/live paypal environment.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to remove Firebase from it completely and focus on what you're trying to accomplish using next.js.  That's the real issue here.

Comment: It's not, though. The firebase functions are uploaded to firebase, completely decoupled from Next. The paypal instance is invoked *inside* the firebase function. I either have to use `SandboxEnvironment` or `LiveEnvironment`

Comment: I've added to my OP to clarify. Hopefully that helps! :)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "uploaded to firebase".  You should probably clarify what you're doing there.  If you're talking about deploying code to Cloud Functions, that's not at all evident here.  Again, Firebase doesn't have a sense of dev or prod - that is a concept of your construction entirely.  Only your code can tell if it's meant to be running in some special way.

Comment: I apologize. I mean, in NextJS dev I want the function to use the PayPal sandbox env. In prod, I want it to use the Live environment. I don't care *how* it's done (either by firebase OR by Next). I just need the function to know whether it's being called from a dev env or a prod env. Maybe even send it as part of the data object?

Comment: Only you and your code can determine if something is meant to run dev or prod.  Firebase can't help you with that.  It's just a cloud service that runs at your command.  I suggest focusing your question on next.js, not Firebase.

Comment: Firebase is only a part of the issue - I'm not saying the solution is there. I'm saying *firebase* is what I want to receive whether or not it's in the dev or prod. I keep saying this - I don't care *how* it is implemented. I just want it to be automated. I'm really not sure how to be any more clear about that, to be honest. How do people automate these things? How is it *usually* done? Surely I can't be the first.

Comment: Your question says "Is there a value I can check in firebase to tell if it's in dev or prod?".  The answer to that is "no, Firebase cannot tell you if you meant for code to run as 'dev' or 'prod.'

Comment: What is the *title* of my question? I'll help you: 'How to tell if firebase function is in development or production?' - I only added my opinion inside to see if it were possible. Now that I know it's not, the broader question remains.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your code is deployed to Firebase or somewhere else.  If it's a web app, then it's all running inside the browser.  I suggest focusing your question on what does matter - building your app with next.js to achieve the result you're looking for.

Comment: My problem is specific to firebase functions, and the env variables associated with it. Firebase functions are *not* running in the browser - They're invoked as a firebase httpsCallable. I'm specifically wanting to be able to set flags for the cloud function (which isn't in the browser). Why would I ask a NextJS specific question when the thing I'm trying to modify is Firebase's flags/variables? I've also rephrased the title.

Comment: Nothing about the code you're showing looks like it was meant to be deployed to Cloud Functions.  It kinda looks like web app code, judging from the imports you're using.  There are no exports for any functions to deploy, and we can't tell what those function need to do at runtime.  NODE_ENV is going to be useless since nothing is setting it.  If you want to look into runtime configuration for your deployed Cloud Functions, use the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: How else are firebase functions run? Aren't they *always* cloud functions unless emulated?

Comment: For Cloud Functions for Firebase you'll typically set environment variables through the CLI and then pick them up in your code as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Answer (score 7):

If the intention is to detect whether the currently running Cloud Function is being emulated or not, you can check the `FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR` environment variable.

```
const isEmulated = process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === "true";
```

**However,** as Doug stated, you shouldn't trust this value blindly. While it has a value now and works, this is an undocumented environment variable used internally by the Firebase Emulator Suite.

The best course of action is to use a different `PROJECT_ID` entirely for your local environment and only deploy to your production project when all is well.

To get your `PROJECT_ID` being used for the active Cloud Function, use:

```
const PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;
```

Then assuming you have a `TEST_PROJECT_ID` and `PROD_PROJECT_ID`, you can now check if you are in production using:

```
const isProduction = PROJECT_ID === PROD_PROJECT_ID;
```

When testing on your system, you should use `TEST_PROJECT_ID`:

```
firebase use TEST_PROJECT_ID
```

And once you've green-lit the changes, you can deploy to `PROD_PROJECT_ID`:

```
firebase deploy --project PROD_PROJECT_ID
```

You can also add these project IDs to `.firebaserc`:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "TEST_PROJECT_ID",
    "TEST": "TEST_PROJECT_ID",
    "PROD": "PROD_PROJECT_ID"
  }
}
```

Inside of your main project directory, create a `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-firebase-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "firebase deploy -P PROD"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "You",
  "license": "NONE"
}
```

Add the same `"deploy"` script to your `functions/package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "firebase deploy -P PROD"
}
```

Now when you want to deploy to production, you use: `firebase deploy -P PROD` or `npm run deploy`.

Make sure when editing your Functions Configuration (`functions.config()` values), you set them on both `TEST_PROJECT_ID` and `PROD_PROJECT_ID` with the appropriate keys.

There are a number of environment variables available to executing Cloud Functions, but only those included by [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#newer_runtimes) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) have guaranteed values:

| Key | Description | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `FUNCTION_TARGET` | Reserved: The function to be executed. |  |
| `FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE` | Reserved: The type of the function: `http` for HTTP functions, and `event` for event-driven functions. |  |
| `K_SERVICE` | Reserved: The name of the function resource. | Replaces `FUNCTION_NAME` in legacy code |
| `K_REVISION` | Reserved: The version identifier of the function. |  |
| `PORT` | Reserved: The port over which the function is invoked. |  |
| `FIREBASE_CONFIG` | Reserved: Firebase project configuration | JSON-encoded string |

Comment: It's not necessarily about whether or not the function is emulated, but that a flag could possibly denote for the functions to use the sandbox/live vars/methods in the function.  It's just weird to me that the logic for that is so undocumented and up to the person. You'd think there was a way to automagically set based on environments.

Comment: While you can use Node's built-in `process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"`, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#best_practices_and_reserved_environment_variables) actively discourage it. Up to you whether you listen to them or not.

Comment: So people have to copy entire firebase backends to do testing? It seems counter-intuitive to me. Especially if something as simple as a flag could be used (that could be changed on dev/build).

Comment: @JoelHager "So people **have to** copy entire firebase backends to do testing?" No, it's a choice and is considered best practice to not test your early solutions in production. Because of the way serverless platforms scale, one infinite loop can easily reap havoc. I'm not suggesting having 3 or 4 projects - just 2. By having two projects you can significantly change your database structure (which will happen working with NoSQL databases), use tools like the [Functions unit-testing framework](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) before deploying them and even explore APIs

Comment: that you could link to the project with service accounts that aren't going to burn the entire house down if you accidentally commit them to some repo. The emulator suite is still relatively new on the scene (open beta) and doesn't catch everything, especially if your node versions differ between your system and what's deployed on Cloud Functions. Think of the split project approach as `local` -> `staging` (deploy to test project) -> `production` (deploy to prod project).

Comment: This is very helpful - one question I have is, what is accomplished by adding "firebase deploy -P PROD" to "scripts" in package.json? Can't we deploy to production with just Firebase use?

Comment: @Redneys It's mainly a safety thing. You should have to go out of your way to do something to your production project. With the above, `firebase deploy` goes to testing, `npm run deploy` goes to prod. Imagine I just passed testing, switched over to production with `firebase use`, deployed my code and went to lunch. After coming back I'm onto working with Firestore, so I use `firebase firestore:delete --all-collections -y` to clear out my test project's Firestore instance. Whelp, I just deleted everything in the production database instead. At least `-P PROD` rings an alarm to tread carefully.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Can you also please confirm what the "-P" accomplishes, given the script is named just "PROD"? Sorry if that's an obvious question - I am just now learning about this.

Comment: @Redneys `-P` is the short form of `--project`. As `"PROD"` is an entry in `.firebaserc`, you can use it as an alias for a project ID instead of the project ID itself. In the answer above, I've bound PROD to the production project ID (and TEST to the dev project's ID). This means these scripts can be copied project to project and you only need update `.firebaserc`.