# Does Firebase Admin SDK deployed at Cloud Run require GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT env var?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-cloud-run

We've deployed a service to Cloud Run which uses Firebase Admin SDK. This service uses multiple auth-related methods. We've found out that if we do not include the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` env var, the method `setCustomUserClaims(...)` throws following error: `Failed to determine project ID for Auth. Initialize the SDK with service account credentials or set project ID as an app option. Alternatively set the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable.`

However, we've also checked that if the env var is not present, other methods, such as `createCustomToken(...)` work just fine. How is this possible? Should we use GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT or not?

Comment: Have you provided [`FIREBASE_CONFIG`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables)? For Firebase Cloud Functions, it's added automatically, but for Cloud Run, you'll need to provide it yourself. See the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311935/3068190) for the list of environment variables consumed by the Functions and Admin SDKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`createCustomToken`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/4bef8fabeb39be2c527862689fe8e49e5410540f/src/auth/token-generator.ts#L123-L182) mints and signs its authentication tokens within the SDK.

This is in contrast to [`setCustomUserClaims`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/4bef8fabeb39be2c527862689fe8e49e5410540f/src/auth/auth-api-request.ts#L1331-L1356) that has to make network calls to do its job, mainly to the endpoint:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/{version}/projects/{projectId}/accounts:update
```

As this endpoint uses the Project ID, it needs to be provided from somewhere.

As of the time of writing, it looks for it in [these locations](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/4bef8fabeb39be2c527862689fe8e49e5410540f/src/utils/index.ts#L71-L121), in the following order:

1. `options.projectId` from `initializeApp()` (this is normally filled in by `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`)
2. `options.credential.projectId` from `initializeApp()`, if the credential is a `ServiceAccountCredential`
3. `process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`
4. `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT`
5. `options.credential.getProjectId()` from `initializeApp()`, if the credential is a `ComputeEngineCredential`