# How can I deploy firebase function as 'NODE_ENV = development'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an application with my team with Firebase, and I want to deploy my app both in development and production environments.

To achieve this, I have done several things. (Details are below)
But NODE_ENV keeps set as 'development' when I deploy it to firebase functions app.
How can I deploy it as 'development' to firebase?

Those are what I have done to achieve my goal.

- Make another firebase project and function for 'production' (Use current firebase project as 'development')
  [firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beuan.png)
- Edit .firebaserc file and set aliases for my projects (to use firebase --use command)
  [.firebaserc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyxMK.png)
- Separate RDS Instance and Slack Monitoring app
- Separate .env files with .env.dev and .env.prod and use secrets based on NODE_ENV
  [set .env files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBbvo.png)
- Add 'dev' script to package.json to deploy as 'NODE_ENV = development'
  [package.json scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oyur.png)

This is the code I wrote to find out is which environment my server is running
[node_env console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGyhy.png)
And this is from my github actions log and firebase console log
[github actions and firebase console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58s8i.jpg)

When I run my app in local with 'serve' command, console.log prints 'development' as I expected.
I guess 'firebase deploy' command automatically changes my NODE_ENV to production when it is deployed.
Or did I make some mistakes to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to have a development and production environment is to have two separate Firebase projects, which you are already making use of. For the sake of an example, let's assume you have `hyositive-app` as your production project and `hyositive-dev` as your development project.

### Defining Deployed Environment Variables

Use of [environment variables with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables) are based on `.env` files compatible with the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package. By default, the following files are supported (ignoring others!):

| Name | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `.env` | Environment variables common to all environments |
| `.env.<projectID>` | Environment variables used when deployed to the named project (e.g. `.env.hyositive-app`) |
| `.env.<alias>` | Environment variables used when deployed to the aliased project (e.g. `.env.dev`). **Note**: `default` is the only alias configured out of the box. `dev`/`prod`/etc. are not defined. |
| `.env.local` | Environment variables used when using emulating functions on your system using the Cloud Functions emulator. |

To use `.env.dev` and `.env.prod`, you will need to define them as project aliases in your `.firebaserc` file (or you can continue using `development` and `production` aliases and just update the filenames to match):

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "hyositive-dev",
    "dev": "hyositive-dev",
    "prod": "hyositive-app"
  }
}
```

This then allows you to use `.env.dev` and `.env.prod` instead of `.env.hyositive-dev` and `.env.hyositive-app` respectively.

### Using Environment Variables

The Cloud Functions runtime (the process that runs your deployed code) defines a number of [built-in environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#reserved-names) that have various purposes (such as allowing you to use `initializeApp()` with no arguments).

In addition to these variables, a handful of language-specific variables are also defined by the runtime to aid in painless deployment of code. However, the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#best_practices_and_reserved_environment_variables) states to not rely on their values unless you set the values yourself.

The Node.js Cloud Functions runtime is built using the [Cloud Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) (however, it is not guaranteed to perfectly match this open source version). Because this runtime executes using Node.js and makes use of other packages such as [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), it sets `NODE_ENV` to `production`, to minimise unexpected behaviour that depends on its value. But as mentioned above, this behaviour should not be relied on even though it is unlikely to change.

To override `NODE_ENV` to `development`, you would add it into `.env.dev`, `.env.hyositive-dev` and/or `.env.local` (as appropriate). Similarly, you should also define `NODE_ENV` as `production` in `.env.prod` or `.env.hyositive-app` (as appropriate).

Rather than rely on `NODE_ENV`, I would recommend defining behaviour around another variable that you have complete control over (such as `HYOSITIVE_ENV`) or compare against the executing project ID to determine whether it is running in the production project or not.

```
const PROD_PROJECT_ID = "hyositive-app",
   // DEV_PROJECT_ID = "hyositive-dev",
      PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId,
      isProduction = PROJECT_ID === PROD_PROJECT_ID;
```

**Note**: This [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311935/3068190) may have some useful background information.

Comment: Wow Thank you so much! I learned a lot from you!!
Wish you all the best :)

Comment: Hello, regrettably, the process.env variables are only defined during runtime. The issue arises because our functions rely on numerous node_modules, each of which configures itself by accessing certain environmental variables. As these modules are imported, they execute prior to runtime, resulting in the expected environmental variables being undefined. How can I address this challenge?