# How to use env properties in Firebase Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, dotenv

I have 2 env files under my functions folder.

Here is the value of `.env` file

```
TOPIC_NAME=projects/project-id-dev/topics/topic-name
```

And here is the value for my `.env.prod` file

```
TOPIC_NAME=projects/project-id-prod/topics/topic-name
```

Then when I deploy my function, I switch the env first by using below command

```
firebase use prod
```

When I'm deploying my function with `firebase deploy --only functions:myFunction`, I could see in the info that firebase is loading both of my env file

```
functions: Loaded environment variables from .env, .env.prod.
```

But, the value that it reads, is the value from the `.env` file rather than from the `.env.prod` file.

Here is how I use the env in my program :

```
import {
  onMessagePublished,
  PubSubOptions,
} from "firebase-functions/v2/pubsub";

export const myFunction = onMessagePublished(
  {
    topic: process.env.TOPIC_NAME
  } as PubSubOptions,
  async (event) => {
  }
```

How could I use the prod env? seems like my prod env not overriding the env file.

**EDIT 1:**

seems like this behavior only happens when I load the env inside the `Options` of the cloud functions. For example when I want to choose the Topic name or the VPC connector for example, it always load the value from .env
Other that that, My program could load the config from .env.prod correctly.

So is this a bug from `Cloud Function` ?

**EDIT 2**
Here is some information from the firebase-debug.log

```
"endpoint": {
   "eventTrigger": {
      "eventType": "google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished",
      "retry": false,
      "eventFilters": {
        "topic": "projects/project-id-dev/topics/topic-name"
      }
    },
   "environmentVariables": {
      "TOPIC_NAME": "projects/project-id-prod/topics/topic-name",
```

**HOW TO REPRODUCE**

Create 2 env properties.

`.env` with value of

```
maxInstance=2
topic=projects/project-id-dev/topics/topic-name
```

`.env.prod` with value of

```
maxInstance=8
topic=projects/project-id-prod/topics/topic-name
```

Cloud function with below source code

```
import {
  onMessagePublished,
  PubSubOptions,
} from "firebase-functions/v2/pubsub";

export const pubsubDefaultOption = (): PubSubOptions => ({
  topic: process.env.topic!,
  maxInstances: parseInt(process.env.maxInstance!),
});

export const myFunction = onMessagePublished(
  pubsubDefaultOption(),
  async (event) => {
  functions.logger.info("maxInstance", process.env.maxInstance); //this will print 8
  functions.logger.info("topic", process.env.topic); //this will print the prod topic
}
```

in package.json, using node v18

```
"engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
```

deploying with below command
`firebase use prod`
`firebase deploy --only functions:myFunction`

the maxInstance used would be 2 rather than 8

Comment: Can you try deploying by using the command suggested in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61477862/18265702). Also have a look at this [Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#deploying_multiple_sets_of_environment_variables) and [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74500190/18265702).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I think its different with my issue. I only cannot get the `env` in the option parameter. I can get the `env` parameter in other places. Seems like it is connected to the `function.yaml` which I believe is a bug of `Firebase CLI`

Comment: If you believe it is a bug, you may report an issue at [Firebase Bug Report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).

Comment: The Firebase CLI command `firebase use prod` means that the dev wants to run firebase commands against a Firebase project with either (a) the project ID of prod (highly unlikely that this dev has that project ID) or (b) a project alias that's called prod. You can check the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases) about project aliases. Note that project aliases must be manually set up by a dev. Also share the documentation you followed to replicate the issue from our end.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni actually in my logs, it is showing that environment variables are correct, which is get it from the `env.prod` which i use by using `firebase use prod`. but above it there is something called eventtrigger, and it is showing the wrong env. When I tracked back, I found in the log that firebase is trying to find the `function.yaml` which doesnt exist, then it get the `function.yaml` from the `node_modules` which means that no matter which env you use, it will always deploy with the option based from the `env` prop.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni this is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd) that I follow to set up my environment

Comment: I have tried with this code [https://codefile.io/f/b0dSzXFTtr](https://codefile.io/f/b0dSzXFTtr) by following this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd) by taking the `env files` with the same content as stated in the Document, which deployed successfully. While deploying I switched the env to `firebase use prod` it loads both the files `functions: Loaded environment variables from .env, .env.prod.`  and reads the value from the `.env.prod` file `Hello Earth and Prod Humans`. Can you share your code once so that I can repro at my end and see.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I have put the how to reproduce in my question. as you can see in there, I could get the `env` var correctly inside the function. The issue is when to update the options/settings/configurations of the CF. for example the maxInstances, topic, vpc, etc based on the env file. Which is in the `PubSubOptions`.

Comment: Can you share the document you are referring to for the code part? When I try to replicate your code I am facing errors. Orelse can you share the complete code?