# Error scheduling automatic Firestore backup

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've followed the steps here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export to create an scheduled function to backup my firestore database.  I'm getting an error in the logs when I run it:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charCodeAt')
>
> at .peg$parsetemplate (
> /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:304
> ) at .Object.peg$parse (
> /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplateParser.js:633
> ) at .PathTemplate (
> /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/pathTemplate.js:55 )

I can't even tell from this where the error is coming from. I tried putting a console.log statement in to see where I'm getting, but I can't figure out where to view the console log at.   Any suggestions:

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
// Replace BUCKET_NAME
const bucket = 'gs://my_firestore_backup'

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = (event, context) => {
  console.log('in function');
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    '(default)'
  );


  return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
      // or define a list of collection IDs:
      // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
      collectionIds: [],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While the Firebase documentation lists a number of [reserved names for environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#reserved-names), many of them are not forwarded to the Cloud Function anymore because they have been removed. However, they are still listed to prevent weird side effects when some library reads/writes to them.

As covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311935/3068190), the environment variables used in the modern node runtime include only the following entries:

> There are a number of environment variables available to executing Cloud Functions, but only those included by [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#newer_runtimes) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) have guaranteed values:
>
> | Key | Description | Note |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `FIREBASE_CONFIG` | Reserved. Firebase project configuration | JSON-encoded string |
> | `FUNCTION_TARGET` | Reserved. The function to be executed. |  |
> | `FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE` | Reserved. The type of the function: `http` for HTTP functions, and `event` for event-driven functions. |  |
> | `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` | Reserved. File path to a JSON file containing credentials | This allows use of `initializeApp()` without arguments. |
> | `K_SERVICE` | Reserved. The name of the function resource. | Replaces `FUNCTION_NAME` in legacy code |
> | `K_REVISION` | Reserved. The version identifier of the function. |  |
> | `PORT` | Reserved. The port over which the function is invoked. |  |

For your code to function as expected, you'll need to pull the project ID out of `FIREBASE_CONFIG`.

```js
const PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId,
  databaseName = client.databasePath(
    PROJECT_ID,
    '(default)'
  );
```

Comment: I tried that and have the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at exports.scheduledFirestoreExport (/workspace/index.js:7:27)

Comment: That would imply that `FIREBASE_CONFIG` is undefined (it's trying to execute `JSON.parse(undefined')` and failing). If both `FIREBASE_CONFIG` and `GCLOUD_PROJECT` are missing, what functions runtime are you using (node/go/etc - i.e. are you running node code from inside a different runtime?) and what command are you deploying your functions with?

Comment: I'm deploying through the google cloud functions page.  Node 18 runtime.